# Ubuntu 18.10 shows black screen with blinking cursor after I rebooted a Thinkpad with hybrid GPUs

Tags: nvidia, hybrid-graphics, 18.10

To switch to Intel GPU from Nvidia 1050Ti, I entered "sudo prime-select intel". Something like: get Intel information showed up on the screen. I logged out and logged in. I went to About but it showed that Nvidia 1050 Ti was still being used. Next, I rebooted the machine. It showed a black screen with a blinking underline cursor on the top left. It stayed there foreover. I pressed the power button continuously. Then, the purple screen with Ubuntu in the middle showed up. After the few dots below Ubuntu turned on, the laptop shut down. I turned on the machine again. Blank purple screen showed up. Then a long list of sentences showed up on the screen quickly. So quick that I could not see what were written on it. Then, again the blinking cursor showed up on the top left. Could you please help to resolve the issue?

Comment: From your other question we know you have Secure Boot enabled. As commented there, just disable it so the Nvidia drivers (unsigned) can be loaded.

Comment: Thanks. I will try. How to disable Secure Boot? Is it via the BIOS?